# Unable to get HTML table rows values using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have some HTML that looks as follows:

```
   <table id="resultsTable" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover table-condensed sortable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Tours Offered</th>
            <th>Average Rating</th>
            <th>Total Reviews</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="searchable">
        @foreach (var item in Model.AccommodationList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="accommodationName">
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.AccommodationName, "ViewHomePage", "AccommodationHomepage", new {accommodationId = item.AccommodationId}, null)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FormattedAddress)
                </td>
                <td>
                     <Deleted for brevity>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalReviews)
                </td>
                <td class="latitudeCell" style="display: none;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Latitude)
                </td>
                <td class="longitudeCell" style="display: none;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Longitude)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am trying to get the value of the accommodation name, latitude and longitude in each row with the following jQuery:

```
    $('#resultsTable tbody tr').each(function () {
        var latitude = $(this).find(".latitudeCell").html();
        var longitude = $(this).find(".longitudeCell").html();
        var accommodationName = $(this).find(".accommodationName").html();

    });
}
```

However I must be doing something incorrectly because I'm not able to get any values.

Comment: How would that look?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken - deleted the first comment - Have you tried `.text()` instead of `.html()`? Also, are you making sure that this script is running after the values are loaded?

Comment: I'm not even able to get inside the for each function

Comment: is the `.each()` function running?  what happens when you try this and how are you trying to show each variable?

Comment: I'm not able to get in the .each() function. So my syntax must be wrong.

Comment: what errors are you getting if any?

Comment: @RandyMinder can you do `$('#resultsTable tbody tr')` from the console and see the results returned?

Comment: Could you please post the HTML as it's seen by the browser, rather than the script that generates said HTML?

Comment: My guess is you are trying to `.each` before the table rows are added to the table.

Comment: Your code works for me, check the console http://jsfiddle.net/kLLg5cpt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript `table.rows` function and `textContent` property to get the inner text of the cell like you can do something like below:

```
for(var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++)
        {           

            var col1 = row.cells[0].textContent;
            var col2 = row.cells[1].textContent;
        }       var col3 = row.cells[2].textContent;
```

Don't use innerText it is much slower than textContent and also doesn't work in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the data correctly but, you don't seem to do anything with the values you obtain from the table. And, after `.each()`, you will not have access to even the values from the last row since you're using local variables. You can create an array that has all the data.

Give this a try:

```
var locations = $('#resultsTable tbody tr').map(function() {
    var location = {};
    location.latitude = $(this).find(".latitudeCell").html();
    location.longitude = $(this).find(".longitudeCell").html();
    location.accommodationName = $(this).find(".accommodationName").html();
    return location;
}).get();
console.log( locations );
//OUTPUT: [{"latitude": "<val>","longitude": "<val>", "accommodationName": "<val>"},{.....},....]
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a fiddle and modified some of your code so I could put text in your cells, I am wondering if this will help you? If not could you write up a small fiddle and I can provide some more assistance.

https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/8cL94hgq/

```
  $('#resultsTable tbody tr').each(function () {
    var latitude = $(this).find(".latitudeCell").html();
    var longitude = $(this).find(".longitudeCell").html();
    var accommodationName = $(this).find(".accommodationName").html();
    alert(latitude);
});
```

Comment: Thank you.. I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me:
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/o20qgazk/3/)

In the code you paste you put a `}` more, try to check if there's some issues with brakets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. In your example, I did not see how you were calling your function. I enclosed your function in `$().ready()` so that it is called when the DOM is ready. You will want to call your function any time the tan;e content changes.

```js
$().ready(function() {

  $('div#cellValues').empty();
  $('div#cellValues').append('<ul></ul>');

  $('#resultsTable tbody tr').each(function(index) {
    var latitude = $(this).find('.latitudeCell').html();
    var longitude = $(this).find(".longitudeCell").html();
    var accommodationName = $(this).find(".accommodationName").html();
    
    $('div#cellValues ul').append('<li>' + accommodationName + ': [' + latitude + ',' + longitude + ']</li>');
  });
});
```

```css
#cellValues {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#cellValues::before {
  content: "Cell Values:";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cellValues"></div>

<table id="resultsTable" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover table-condensed sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company Name</th>
      <th>Tours Offered</th>
      <th>Average Rating</th>
      <th>Total Reviews</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="searchable">
    <tr>
      <td class="accommodationName">accomidationName1</td>
      <td>FormattedAddress1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>TotalReviews1</td>
      <td class="latitudeCell" style="display: none;">Latitude1</td>
      <td class="longitudeCell" style="display: none;">Longitude1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="accommodationName">accomidationName2</td>
      <td>FormattedAddress2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>TotalReviews2</td>
      <td class="latitudeCell" style="display: none;">Latitude2</td>
      <td class="longitudeCell" style="display: none;">Longitude2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="accommodationName">accomidationName3</td>
      <td>FormattedAddress3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>TotalReviews3</td>
      <td class="latitudeCell" style="display: none;">Latitude3</td>
      <td class="longitudeCell" style="display: none;">Longitude3</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```